# Submit Form When User Clicks OK on Confirm Box

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a javascript in my HTML form that runs when the user clicks the Submit button. It displays the total price for the users order and has the buttons for "ok" and "cancel". I want the form to be submitted when the user clicks "ok", but not submitted if the user clicks "cancel". It currently submits the form when either button is pressed. How do I keep it from submitting the form if "cancel" is clicked?

This is my short script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function calculate()
            {
                var gPrice
                var aPrice
                var sPrice
                var total

                gPrice = document.getElementById("grapeorderquantity").value * 4.0;
                aPrice = document.getElementById("appleorderquantity").value * 3.0;
                sPrice = document.getElementById("strbryorderquantity").value * 3.5;

                total = (gPrice + aPrice + sPrice) * 1.08;

                confirm("This is your total: " + total);
            }
        </script>
```

This is the HTML for my submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return calculate()" />
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the cancel button?  You know what, show the HTML for the whole form.

Comment: There is no HTML for the OK and CANCEL buttons. They are automatically generated when using the confirm window in javascript.

Comment: @Jason9024 - You need to block the `submit` event on the `form` element, not the `click` on the `submit` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this to your function:

```
if(confirm("This is your total: " + total)) { // confirm returns true = OK clicked
    return true;
}
else { // confirm returns false = Cancel clicked
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the second option didn't work (explained in comment on JacobM's answer, but using the if/else does. Thanks!